# Imagejpeg returns false but file exists

Tags: php, wordpress

Yesterday I got an output `imagejpg()` (albeit unreadable character because I havent set the header) but today nothing. The only thing I can that I changed is enabling special permissions on the server. Any idea what else could have affected it? The output for the following code is:

```
The file exists
Imagejpeg: FALSE
Imagejpeg: FALSE
The file is writable
```

The output is the same if `$filename = $URL`.

The code:

```
clearstatcache();
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/thumbnails/sb1778/1.jpg";
$URL = get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/thumbnails/sb1778/1.jpg";



if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "<BR> The file exists";
} else {
    echo "<BR> The file does NOT exist";
}

if((imagejpeg($filename)) === true)
{echo "<BR> Imagejpeg: TRUE";}
else {echo "<BR>  Imagejpeg: FALSE";}
imagejpeg($filename);

if((imagejpeg($URL)) === true)
{echo "<BR> Imagejpeg: TRUE";}
else {echo "<BR>  Imagejpeg: FALSE";}
imagejpeg($URL);




if (is_writable($filename )) { 
    echo '<BR> The file is writable';
} else { echo '<BR> The file is NOT writable';
}
```

Comment: You should start with the manual, the first parameter for `imagejpeg()` is not a string.

Comment: The manual you say? Interesting. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The image needs to go through the `Imagescreatefromjpeg` function first:

```
 $filename = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/thumbnails/sb1778/1.jpg");
```